# istream (ostream) vs. bool

Tags: c++, types, casting

Here is a C++ code which reads as many words
from a given text file as possible until it meets EOF.

```
string text;
fstream inputStream;


inputStream.open("filename.txt");

while (inputStream >> text)
    cout << text << endl;

inputStream.close();
```

My question is:

- what procedure exactly is performed behind on converting the condition of the while loop (i.e., inputStream >> text) into a boolean values (i.e., true or false)?

My own answer for the question is:

- To my understanding, inputStream >> text is supposed to return another (file) input stream. The stream seems to be NULL when EOF arrives. The NULL may be defined as 0, which is equivalent to false.

Does my answer make sense? Even if my answer does make sense, such conversion of InputStream to bool doesn't make me so comfortable. :)

Comment: you'll see this idiom of checking for non-null and non-zero all over C and C++ code. One gets quite used to reading beerBottles = 99; while(beerBottles) beerBottles--;

Comment: The reason is so that you can do things like `cin >> x >> y;`  If `operator>>` returned a boolean that would be impossible, but `nullptr` (or the implicit conversion to bool in this case) will evaluate to `false`, so win-win.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> what procedure exactly is performed behind on converting the condition of the while loop (i.e., inputStream >> text) into a boolean values (i.e., true or false)?

`operator>>` returns a reference to the stream.

In C++11 the reference is then converted to a `bool` by the stream's `operator bool()` function, which returns the equivalent of `!fail()`.

In C++98 the same is achieved by using `operator void*()`, and the returned pointer is either `NULL` to indicate failure or a non-null pointer if `fail()` is false, which is then implicitly converted to a `bool` in the `while` evaluation.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I expected on my posting. Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI for the OP - the reason `operator void*()` was used pre C++11 was to avoid incidentally compiling doubtful code like `stream1 << stream2` or `stream1 + stream2` by having each stream yield a `bool`, then having those convert further to integers (`true`->`1`, `false`->`0`) for a probably-unintended integral operation.  C++11 actually has `explicit operator bool()` - this newly supported use of `explicit` inhibits conversions outside boolean contexts.  `void*`s didn't work brilliantly - `stream1 < stream2` was still legal - but `explicit` fixes that too.

Comment: @user3509406 If this answer solved your problem, accept it by pressing the green tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer has been perfectly answered by user657267. But I am adding one more example to understand the answer more easily.

```
// evaluating a stream
#include <iostream>     // std::cerr
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream is;
  is.open ("test.txt");
  if (is) {           <===== Here, an example of converting ifstream into bool
    // read file
  }
  else {
    std::cerr << "Error opening 'test.txt'\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Ref. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/